# Is there a way to make a if(null) do something

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap

I have a hashmap of States and capitals

Currently a user inputs the state and it will give them the corresponding capital

and then they will type done when they want to kick out of the program

Is there a way to make an if statement that would take the null that the hashmap would send if there was no said state in it?

Like if I ask for Canada it will return null because there is no state named Canada.

Is there a way to use the null it sends back in a for loop so I can do something like

```
if(null)
{
   say that that isn't a capital
}
else
{
   say the capital of what was inserted
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like `if (capital == null) {` - or did I misunderstand?

Comment: yes, Hovercraft got it, thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, simply do what you are asking:

```
String capital = stateMap.get(testValue);
if (capital == null) {
   // error message
   System.err.printf("%s is not a valid state, please try again%n", testValue);
} else {
   // output a valid result
   System.out.printf("The capital of %s is %s%n", testValue, capital);
}
```